# Several good CPUs with a very bad hash

Tags: mining-pools, cpu-mining, mining

I have a question. I have 5 good machines mining Monero. In average each machine give me about 300H/s.

So if I have 5 machines, I am suppose to have 1500 H/s.

I am not doing solo mining but I am using a monero pool with 12MH/s.

My question is.. why when I check the pool website I never got my 1500H/s ? I see 1000, 600, 900, 1200, and other variations but never 1500H/s.

Is the pool the problem ? Should I try solo mining ?

Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

That is normal because the pool stats are generated based on actual number of accepted shares. The pool is counting how many valid shares it receives from you in some time window and calculates your average hashrate based on that. It's an estimate - the pool can not monitor your CPU cycles to know exactly how much hashes it actually generates to complete a share.

Because the process is not deterministic, it will always oscillate. Your CPU is really just rolling random numbers, doing some calculation on them, and checking it vs the share target. The pool doesn't know how many attempts it took to guess a solution, but the faster the CPU, the faster you'll be able to find a solution and the pool can only monitor the time between two solutions to estimate the hashrate.

Note that there's always some wasted time when communicating with the pool. You don't want to be finding shares too fast otherwise you'll have too much overhead just for "talking" with the pool. If you're solving shares too quickly, try increase the difficulty and see what happens, you could get more effective H/s. Just avoid setting it too high otherwise you'll get a lot stale shares so you're really looking for some optimum there. Trial & error :) Network latency is also a factor, so you might want to try a pool with the lowest ping.

Comment: I see !!! many thanks.. I am using Wolfram Warptangent (minerd cryptonight) but I do not see option to increase the difficulty ... I guess I did not understand this part.

Comment: and in other words.. does not matter if I have 5 independent machines with different IPs.. the hash displayed by the pool is gonna be the one guessed by the pool.. if this statement is correct, my illusion to have 10 machines with 300 H/s and have 3000 H/s capacity is wrong. Can you confirm this ?

Comment: Yes. If you use the same address&password with the pool, it should show you the total for all machines but it will never be exactly 3000, maybe 2700 or something, depends on luck factor and some inefficiencies as described above. If you use different "password" for each machine, some pools can show you individual stats for each machine